# Is it a valid edit to replace mis-heard word with correct one?

Tags: discussion, editing

I'm trying to decide if I should roll back [this edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/55470/revisions) or leave it be...

General situation is:

- OP mis-heard the word (usually proper noun) and as a result was unable to Google it properly
- An answer identifies correct spelling.
- The edit to the question replaces incorrect spelling with correct one.

**Pros:** The question is now more easily searchable

**Cons:** The question turns from a perfectly valid one into what someone may percieve as trivially obvious (the specific example I gave has a subtlety to it that survives even that edit, by asking for the meaning of a phrase instead of simply what the word was... but in a general situation that's not always the case).

Comment: ...why are you posting opposed answers?  This is meta, not a poll station; people with an opinion will post their own, including reasons...

Comment: ...and now I'm imagining a spartan.  I never even watched 300 (and never wanted to).

Comment: @Izkata - Latent MPD?

Comment: ...[Music Player Daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon)?  (My top result in Google)

Comment: @Izkata - sorry, looks like it got renamed to DID while I wasn't looking.

Comment: MPD stands for Multiple Personality Disorder, which is now known as DID, Dissociative Identity Disorder, as a general FYI.

Answer (score 6):

Rollback that edit as the question asker is asking why **that specific (incorrectly-heard) thing** was said. Changing it is too drastic an edit, although in this case it doesn't drastically change the what the answer is.

Answer (score 3):

Don't edit it (or roll back the edit).

The edit turns the question from a perfectly valid one into what someone may percieve as trivially obvious.

<sub>NOTE: the specific example linked here has a subtlety to it that survives even that edit, by asking for the meaning of a phrase instead of simply what the word was... but in a general situation that's not always the case.</sub>

Comment: The main issue here is that edits that change the meaning of *answers* should be reverted. If the answer is "You misheard the name, it was actually Hippocrates", and then the question is changed to "Hippocrates", it makes the answer nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

Edit it by:

- Adding "([sic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic))" to indicate that the spelling was "intentionally" wrong
- And also include corrected spelling right after, in parenthesis, or elsewhere in the question, to allow better searching.

E.g. this question could be edited to:

Subject: "What did emergency medical hologram mean when he referenced Epocrates {sic} in S1E2 Parallax?"

Body: "Now I know how Epocrates {{sic}} felt when the king needed him to trim a hangnail?"

Body: "Spelling correction: Correction: Hippocrates not Epocrates"

Answer (score -1):

Let the edit stand as it is. Improved searchability outweighs the cons.